# Oracle Virtualbox Ubuntu Recovery

Tags: command-line, bash, virtualbox, oracle

I was trying to run a bash script at at startup in oracle virtualbox ubuntu 16.04, so I added the bash file in 
**/etc/init.d** as well as in **~./config/upstart.** When I rebooted my system, it is starting but then just a blank screen comes with no desktop, nothing. Anyone got an idea how to correct it?
The bash file starts with **#!bin/bash** and then normal commands

Comment: Go to recovery and mount filesystem then get rid of those scripts...

Comment: I am doing the same, went in recovery mode and typed cd ~/.config/upstart, but it is showing no such file or directory..

Comment: pls mount the filesystem in `rw` like this: `mount -o remount,rw /` before doing anything

Comment: yes I did that too

Comment: Where you able to remove that of `/etc/init.d`?

Comment: yes I am able to access that folder and did not find the startup bash script. May be I have deleted it before this mess started. So apparently, it is  `~./config/upstart` folder only.

Comment: Please note: `~/.config` not `~./config`. So reboot and let see

Comment: I tried `~/.config`. I am able to access `config` folder and after going in this `config` folder, when I do `cd upstart` or `cd autostart`, it says no file or directly. And I think I have forgotten was it upstart or autostart, so was trying both.

Comment: do a `ls -al` to see what there...

Comment: it is showing ` . .. dconf gedit nautilus`

Comment: then perhaps you have remove it as it aught to be there! Does a restart stil fail?

Comment: yes a restart still failed..  :(  do I have any other option to store it back?

Comment: The recovery shell will be a *root* shell, so `~` will refer to `root`; if you want to remove or edit a script in you *user's* home you will need to specify that explicitly i.e. `/home/username/.config/upstart`

Comment: Please redo the whole process and use the full path as stated by steeldriver...

Comment: ok thank you, I will do the whole process again and let you know the results

Comment: Thanks a lot George and steeldriver...  :).  I recovered the system back.